# address / pointer assigning in var type In swift

Tags: swift

i am new to Swift i am just starting to learning it, i have a doubt that is killing my mind that is, if swift is pure object oriented language and every thing in swift is object so if i write

```
var aValue = 2  //step 1
var bValue = 5  //step 2
```

that means variable a and b should be treated as references holding their correspond values 2 and 5 of `Int` type , so after this if i write

```
aValue = bValue   //step 3
aValue = 0   //step 4
```

then as step-3 statement address of bValue should be assigned to the variable aValue and hereby aValue and bValue both should be pointing to the same object ( 
for example if this was written in java ) and each operation with aValue should affect the bValue ( as they are pointing to the same object ) means and bValue should have the value 0 i.e. `aValue = 0` and `bValue = 0` after step-4 but in practically the object of bValue is copied to the aValue and they are treating independent to each other so how that happened

can any one explain this!

Comment: *"every thing in swift is object"* – where did you get that from? I would recommend to read "A Swift Tour" and then "Classes and Structures" in the Swift language reference.

Comment: Java doesn't work like that for primitive types.

Comment: Not even Swift (or Java) objects behave how you're describing – if you have two references to the same object, and then assign some other reference to one of those references, the other one doesn't magically update to point to the same object. They will point to *different* objects. Sounds like you're thinking of C++ references.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html)

> In Swift, many basic data types such as String, Array, and Dictionary
>   are implemented as structures. This means that data such as strings,
>   arrays, and dictionaries are copied when they are assigned to a new
>   constant or variable, or when they are passed to a function or method.
>
> This behavior is different from Foundation: NSString, NSArray, and
>   NSDictionary are implemented as classes, not structures. Strings,
>   arrays, and dictionaries in Foundation are always assigned and passed
>   around as a reference to an existing instance, rather than as a copy.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different types in Swift; reference types and value types. You can read about them here https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10 but in short, ints are value types and thus are copied on write so when you assign bvalue's value to avalue, bvalue is copied so the two vars are still 'independent'.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, there are value types and reference types. In general, structs are value types, while classes are reference types.
Most primitive types in Swift, such as Int are implemented using structures and hence these are value types.
See the [official blog post](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10) about value and reference types.

Answer (score 0):

```
var aValue = 2  //step 1
var bValue = 5  //step 2
```

the both variables called value types.which means both have unique memory address it wont affect all if you are changing value to anyone of them.

```
aValue = bValue   //step 3 - bValue is copied to aValue
aValue = 0   //step 4 -  Changes aValue, not bbValue
```